# How to add an observer to a method on Objective C

Tags: ios

I don´t know if this is possible but I need to add an observer to the method - `(void)setTargetRect:(CGRect)targetRect inView:(UIView *)targetView`
from the UIMenuController class. I need to know the targetRect of this object. If this is possible, Apple will allow this? Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165790/whats-the-nicest-way-to-do-observer-observable-in-objective-c-iphone-version

Comment: What exactly is your requirement. Can you please share some more details. Probably you might want to add an observer for some property in UIMenuController class.

Comment: Can you tell me the object you want to observe? I mean is it a view or something?